# perl - regex help matching mulitple values in single string

Tags: regex, perl

Most of the regex examples I am seeing does a match `$line=~ m/dog/`, but once I find a match how do I extract that value only to store in a variable?

```
/home/test/dog/.last_file_sent.yahoo@jedi.ucsb.edu
```

I want to match `dog` or any 3 letter word after `/home/test/` and put that in a variable. Then on the same string match a specific name like `ucsb` and place that in another variable so I can print them out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two pairs of capturing parentheses.

```
my $pattern = qr{/home/test/(\w{3}).*[.](\w+)[.]edu};

while (my $line = <>) {
    my ($three_letter_word, $school) = $line=~/$pattern/;
    print "$three_letter_word | $school\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2/lib/File/Basename.pm)- Parse file paths into directory, filename and suffix.
for example:

```
use strict;
use File::Basename;
my $file = '/home/test/dog/.last_file_sent.yahoo@jedi.ucsb.edu';
my($filename, $directories) = fileparse($file);
```

filename will give you `.last_file_sent.yahoo@jedi.ucsb.edu` and
 directories will give you `/home/test/dog/`

To extract a value or capture a value, you have to put a round bracket around your regex like

```
$directories =~ m/(dog)/;   
my $extract_value = $1;
```

see [Extracting matches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Extracting-matches) for more detail of how to extract parts of a string that matched.

Comment: this is a good answer too. thanks for your help and the link to the docs.